# How to create a combine pipeline that emits the option tapped

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have a dropdown that on selection shows some options. I want to create a publisher that emits the option that is then tapped.

I have a property indicating the selectedDropdown

```
@Published var selectedDropdown: DropdownViewModel?
```

```
struct DropdownViewModel {
  var options: [DropdownOption]
  ...
}
```

```
struct DropdownOption {
    var select = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    ...
}
```

Here's where I've got to

```
  var optionTap: AnyPublisher<DropdownOption, Never> {
        let selectedDropdown = $selectedDropdown.compactMap { $0 }
        let options = selectedDropdown.map { $0.options }
        let selectStream = options.map {
            $0.map { option in option.select.flatMap { Just(option) } }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        return selectStream
    }
```

I want a stream of `DropdownOption` being emitted when there is a select.send(()) but here I map over a map which isn't going to work - is there an operator I can use here?

Edit:

This is how I did the actual dropdown taps...

```
  var dropdownTaps: AnyPublisher<DropdownViewModel?, Never> {
        Publishers.Merge3(
            tap(on: dropdown1),
            tap(on: dropdown2),
            tap(on: dropdown3)
        ).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

```
  private func tap(on dropdown: DropdownViewModel) -> AnyPublisher<DropdownViewModel?, Never> {
        dropdown.tap.map { dropdown }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

```
dropdownTaps.assign(to: &$selectedDropdown)
```

I'd like to acheive something similar if possible

Comment: I'm confused about how you want each `DropdownOption` to be emitted. You have an array of those, but you want them to only be emitted if their own subject sends a `Void` value?

Comment: Yes but I'm open to a better solution/structure. I'd like to assign the emitted `DropdownOption` to a `selectedOption` @Published property - ideally following how I did the actual dropdown taps which I will add to the question. Thanks